# How to stop video in tab?

Tags: jquery, video, tabs

I have a tab interface on my website that contains images and a youtube video on the last tab. All works fine however everytime I switch tabs the video doesn't stop playing. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

This is what I got:

[Click Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/EPEDr/1)

Comment: This can be reduced down to a small testcase involving a single div containing the video and a button that shows and hides the div on click. At that point you could correctly include code in your question. One possible fix would be to refresh the iframe, though the current position and d/l progress will be reset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EPEDr/3/)** — Switching tabs pauses any playing videos.

By using the **[YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)**, you can play/pause/stop videos.

```
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<iframe width="510" height="287" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('iframe[src*="//www.youtube.com/embed/"]').each(function(i) {
      this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note the `?enablejsapi=1` query string appended to the YouTube embed URL in the `iframe`.

Comment: Oops actually it didn't work after copying all the code. Oh boy :(
I really don't know what's wrong as it worked perfectly in the demo page o_O

I think it's better if u see exactly what I have


[Click Here to download](http://creativusmouse.com/tabs.zip)

Thank u so much for your time!

Comment: 1. You're missing the `<html>` tag directly after `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: 2. Your jQuery encapsulation is wrong in scripts.js
Code inside `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` does not wait for the DOM to be ready and executes immediately.
All your jQuery should be contained inside `jQuery(function($){ ... });`, which will cause it to run once the DOM is ready (document has loaded).
See http://jsfiddle.net/9YaP9/

Comment: Oh sorry thank u very much! I just got a little busy in the meantime. Just tested the script and it works perfectly. 
Once again thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: You can remove the 'http:' from the selector to avoid any SSL issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe class="popup-youtube-player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>

$('.tabs li a').on('click', function() {

$('.popup-youtube-player')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'); 
});
```

for detail visit [How to pause or stop youtube, vimeo and html5 video on tab change](http://findmecode.com/pause-stop-youtube-vimeo-html5-video-tab-change/)