# stop all videos when a new video is played

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

I need some help with Youtube API and embeded videos. I want to stop all iframe videos (here i have taken only 3, but there are several videos)running on the current page when a new youtube video is clicked. At one point of time, only one iframe youtube video should run. I have gone thruogh documentation [https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference][1] and was able to write till here...

Updated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var player;
             function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }

            var done = false;
              function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                    alert("hi5");
                    player1.stopVideo();
                    player2.stopVideo();
                    done = true;
                }
               }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <ul class="image-grid" id="list"> 
            <li>
                <iframe id="player" width="385" height="230" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/erDxb4IkgjM?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe id="player1" width="385" height="230" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wSrA5iQGlDc?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe id="player2" width="385" height="230" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c7b_WLkztXc?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATED

1. onStateChange event is not getting triggered(working)
2. In this example i have 3 videos, in reality it has more videos instead of writing onPlayerStateChange for each video..is it possible to use an array for all the videos..and in the function onPlayerStateChange, to write player[].stopVideo() and this.playvideo()..something of this sort..(help required)
   please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LakshmiV/kn5Sf/
   Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this...

Give every iframe a class so that it can be identified as an iframe for youtube player.
Here I have given "yt_players"

Now you can use the below code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    players = new Array();

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var temp = $("iframe.yt_players");
        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            var t = new YT.Player($(temp[i]).attr('id'), {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            players.push(t);
        }
    }
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            var temp = event.target.a.src;
            var tempPlayers = $("iframe.yt_players");
            for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                if (players[i].a.src != temp) 
                    players[i].stopVideo();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Have updated the code...This should be of help to you.

See it in here...http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/Y8P7y/

Comment: what you can do is debug the data that comes in the event parameter and check if you can see which player is being played. Depending on that you can try switching the videos off and on.

Comment: had missed the call to onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(). Check now

Comment: Hey it is working...you need to wait and see when the video starts...If you want you can even check for the event 
YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING and put other videos to stop. And yes you can store the object in an array and get the id of the iframe and stop the video accordingly

Comment: Take a look at the code now...it should help you out...Also updated the link http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/Y8P7y/ hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a ton Anubhav! Its working like a charm..I can vote up only once:( if not i will give you 100 votes..ur prompt response and technical skills are highly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @satya...Glad I could be of your help :)

Comment: Concept works very well.  On the `onPlayerStateChange` function you do not need to 'search' for all instances of `iframe.yt_players` again though as this has already been defined in the 'players' array during execution of the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`.  By removing `tempPlayers` if will make your code more efficient.

Comment: Doesn't work as a logged in Youtube-user in Google Chrome (ver 33).

Comment: @SebNilsson this code was written for a specific scenario. It would be great if you could share your question link along with the code you are using, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: I am looking at jsfiddle..doesn't work..all videos playing simultaneously..

Answer (score 6):

Great answer by [Coby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694854/coby) to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13260520/835822

Using [an attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) you can target any iframe that comes from Youtube and then using [jQuery's each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you can loop through all of them.

```
$(function(){
  $('iframe[src*="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').each(function(i) {
  this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
});
```

});

Comment: Great solution. I used `'iframe[src*="//www.youtube.com/embed/"]'` so that http or https will both work.

Answer (score 3):

Good concept, but event.target.a.src doesn't work! Changed it to event.target.getVideoUrl() and it works fine. check it out here

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    var temp = event.target.getVideoUrl();
    var tempPlayers = $("iframe.yt_players");
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (players[i].getVideoUrl() != temp) players[i].stopVideo();

    }
}
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8P7y/82/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **EMBEDYOUTUBEURL** with your exact YouTube URL.

```js
jQuery(“.career_video_frame”).on(“click”, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let original_src = jQuery(“.owl-item.active .career_video_frame iframe”)[0].src;
            jQuery(“.career_video_frame .career_overlay”).removeClass(“positionRelative”);
            jQuery(“iframe”).each(function() {
                framesrc = this.src;
                updateframesrc = framesrc.replace(‘&autoplay=1’, ”);
                // jQuery(this).attr(“src”, updateframesrc);
                jQuery(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage(‘{“event”:”command”,”func”:”stopVideo”,”args”:””}’, ‘*’);
                // console.log(updateframesrc);
            });
            let frame_ID = jQuery(this).attr(“id”);
            jQuery(“.career_video_frame#” + frame_ID + ” .career_overlay”).addClass(“positionRelative”);
            jQuery(“.owl-item.active .career_video_frame#” + frame_ID + ” iframe”)[0].src = original_src + “&autoplay=1”;
            // console.log(frame_ID);
        });
```

```css
 .career_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
 .career_overlay.positionRelative {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id=”frm_0″ class=”t-entry-visual-cont career_video_frame”>
<div class=”career_overlay”></div>
<iframe src=”https://www.EMBEDYOUTUBEURL.com?feature=oembed&width=640&height=390&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1″ width=”640″ height=”360″ frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen=”allowfullscreen”></iframe>
</div>

<div id=”frm_1″ class=”t-entry-visual-cont career_video_frame”>
<div class=”career_overlay”></div>
<iframe src=”https://www.EMBEDYOUTUBEURL.com?feature=oembed&width=640&height=390&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1″ width=”640″ height=”360″ frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen=”allowfullscreen”></iframe>
</div>
```