# How to play sound file one by one on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I have some mp3 format audio files. I want to play it on click event in JavaScript. I tried some code. But issue is that, when I click multiple link then all respective audio play together. 
But I want play one by one. Means previous audio will stop and play current clicked audio.
JavaScript code is -

```
var audiofullpathdufault=audioPath;
var xNewaudiodefault = document.createElement("AUDIO");
if (xNewaudiodefault.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) 
{
    xNewaudiodefault.setAttribute("src",audiofullpathdufault);
}
else 
{
    xNewaudiodefault.setAttribute("src",audiofullpathdufault);
}
xNewaudiodefault.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
xNewaudiodefault.pause();
xNewaudiodefault.play();
```

My audio output is - If click on more than one link then previous audio will stop or pause and current clicked audio will play.

Comment: add click listener and stop all audios on page before playing the selected one?

Comment: I have add pause() method. but its not working here. why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [stop all videos when a new video is played](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890267/stop-all-videos-when-a-new-video-is-played)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to declare a function called onclick which stops previous audio and plays new audio :

```
function playAudio (src) {
    if(window.audio) {
       audio.pause();
    }
    window.audio = new Audio (src);
    window.audio.play();
}
```

now all you need to do is to call it when you click on a link:

```
<tag onclick="playAudio('/link/to/audio.mp3')"> Click Me </tag>
```

notice I used `window.audio` to make it global so that we can stop previous playing audio