# How to stop local videos playing simultaneously in php

Tags: php, iframe

I have 8 videos in my page which is retrieved from database. They are playing simultaneously. How can I make them pause if I click another video to play. I found for youtube videos but not for local videos. Can u suggest how to get off from this problem?

Check my code below:

```
<?php 

include 'config.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>



</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<label style="font-size:2em;color:tomato"><b>Today's Video</b></label>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php $sql="SELECT video_path FROM videos WHERE category =  'Films'
 AND postedby =  'Admin'";
 $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
 {
 $vid=$row['video_path'];

  }
  ?>

  <iframe src=<?php echo $vid; ?> id="video-1" height="150" width="150" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  </td>
  <td>

  <?php $sql="SELECT video_path FROM videos WHERE category =  'Political'
  AND postedby =  'Admin'";
  $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql); 
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
  $vid=$row['video_path'];

    }
  ?>

  <iframe src=<?php echo $vid; ?> id="video-2" height="150" width="150" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" value="Films" readonly style="font-
  weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#f7c02a;border:none;text-
  align:center;font-size:1em;width:150px">
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" value="Political" readonly style="font-
  weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#40cc16;border:none;text-
  align:center;font-size:1em;width:150px">
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <?php $sql="SELECT video_path FROM videos WHERE category =  'Shopping'
  AND postedby =  'Admin'";
  $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
  $vid=$row['video_path'];

   }
  ?>  
  <iframe src=<?php echo $vid; ?> height="150" width="150" frameborder="0" 
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?php $sql="SELECT video_path FROM videos WHERE category =  'Services'
  AND postedby =  'Admin'";
  $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
   {

    $vid=$row['video_path'];

   }
  ?>  
  <iframe src=<?php echo $vid; ?> height="150" width="150" frameborder="0" 
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" value="Shopping" readonly style="font-
  weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#e825ce;border:none;         
  text-align:center;font-size:1em;width:150px"> 
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" value="Services" readonly style="font-
  weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#607c03;border:none;         
  text-align:center;font-size:1em;width:150px">
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <?php 
  $sql="SELECT video_path FROM videos WHERE category =  'Events'
  AND postedby =  'Admin'";
  $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {     
   $vid=$row['video_path'];

    }
  ?>  
  <iframe src=<?php echo $vid; ?> height="150" width="150" frameborder="0" 
  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </center>
  </body>
  </html>
```

If I play video in one iframe, remaining videos should pause or refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from [stop all videos when a new video is played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890267/stop-all-videos-when-a-new-video-is-played). Thank you Satya and Anubhav Ranjan. I am posting my code. Please verify and suggest any further modifications.

```
<?php 

include 'config.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api">
    </script>
 </head>

  <body>
  <center style="margin-left:0px">
  <label style="font-size:2em;color:tomato"><b>Today's Video</b></label>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td> 
  <?php
  $sql="SELECT `video_path` FROM `videos` WHERE `category`='Films' 
  and postedby='Admin' and id in (select max(id) as id FROM `videos` 
  WHERE `category`='Films')";
  $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

  if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {

   $vid=$row['video_path']."?
   rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=1;controls=1";

    echo '<iframe src='.$vid.' class="yt_players" height="150" width="150" 
    id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" ></iframe>
    <br/>';


     }
    ?>
   </td>
   <td>

    <?php
    $sql="SELECT `video_path` FROM `videos` WHERE 
   `category`='Political' and postedby='Admin' and id in (select max(id) as 
    id FROM `videos` WHERE `category`='Political')";
    $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {

    $vid=$row['video_path']."?
    rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=1;controls=1";

    echo '<iframe src='.$vid.' class="yt_players" height="150" width="150" 
    id="player1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" >
    </iframe><br/>';


     }
    ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td><br/></td><td><br/></td></tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <?php
   $sql="SELECT `video_path` FROM `videos` WHERE 
   `category`='Shopping' and postedby='Admin' and id in (select max(id) as 
   id FROM `videos` WHERE `category`='Shopping')";
   $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

   if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
   {

    $vid=$row['video_path']."?
    rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=1;controls=1";

    echo '<iframe src='.$vid.' height="150" class="yt_players" width="150" 
    id="player2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" >
    </iframe><br/>';


    }
   ?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?php
  $sql="SELECT `video_path` FROM `videos` WHERE `category`='Services' and 
  postedby='Admin' and id in (select max(id) as id FROM `lookon_videos` 
  WHERE `category`='Services')";
  $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

  if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {

   $vid=$row['video_path']."?
   rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=1;controls=1";

    echo '<iframe src='.$vid.' class="yt_players" height="150" width="150" 
   id="player3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" ></iframe>
   <br/>';


   }
   ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var players = new Array();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var temp = $("iframe.yt_players");
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var t = new YT.Player($(temp[i]).attr('id'), {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        players.push(t);

    }
  }
   onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();

   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        var temp = event.target.a.src;
       // var tempPlayers = $("iframe.yt_players");
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i].a.src != temp) 
                players[i].stopVideo();
        }
    }
    }
  </script>

  </center>
  </body>
  </html>
```